# Can't declare variables in Powershell

Tags: ruby, variables, declaration

I am following along the Learn Ruby the Hard Way book and I am having some trouble with Powershell. I have gotten Ruby running in the shell and I can perform calculations and run .rb files. However, when I try to do a simple variable assignment such as:

```
i = 4
```

I get a large red error message saying something along the lines of "i : The term 'i' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program etc..."

Why is it trying to read this as a script/program name instead of a variable assignment?

Using Ruby 2.0.0p576 (x64) on a 64 bit Windows 8 machine if that helps at all.

I also realized that it won't allow me to even do basic comparisons like 4 == 9. It tries to read that as an assignment for some reason.

Comment: You probably want to start `irb` first. Powershell is not a ruby REPL.

Comment: I'll ask here as well incase you missed my comment below. I was previously using the ruby -v command to start. What is the difference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try IRB command ? for calculations and mimics you need to run IRB first.

Comment: I will have to try this when I get home. I was previously just using the command ruby -v. What is the difference here?